# Universal Links and the Bundle Itentifier vs Domain Matching

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, url-scheme, ios-universal-links

My application is set up for Universal Links via a QR Code and the Native Camera. My problem is, the Bundle Identifier domain does not match the domain where the apple-app-site-association file lives.

My bundle identifier uses my company's domain (due to my developer account) and the app we are targeting lives on a different project domain.

```
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "MYID.com.companyname.projectname",
        "paths": [ "*" ]
      }
    ]
```

The urls in the app and the apple-app-site-association are hosted on

```
https://projectname.hostname.com
```

One more note is that in my associated domains I have the following entry.

```
applinks:projectname.hostname.com
```

My apple-app-site-association file gets validated correctly when I send

```
projectname.hostname.com
to
https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/#resultsbox
```

What should I put in my QR Code (or link) to successfully launch my app?

Comment: The "domain" in the bundle id doesn't need to match the universal link domain.  It is recommended that you use a reverse-domain style string for your bundle id but this isn't required and it is simply a unique string across the App Store. There is no other meaning to it. As long as you have the right bundle id in the site association file it is all good

Comment: Thank you for the info! Do I need the associated domains bit in the project settings?

Comment: Yes, you need to follow all of the necessary steps as per the documentation.

Comment: Everything is in place, but the urls always open in chrome. https://projectname.hostname.com or https://projectname.hostname.com/path when scanned should open in my app right? The toast that shows before going to the link says "open in" chrome. If all is set up right that should show "open in" my app and not chrome right? I have been deleting my app with each install to make sure it re-downloads the association file.

Comment: You can perform a sys diagnose in your device to capture the site association information that your device has collected. https://www.wwt.com/article/using-sysdiagnose-on-ios-to-troubleshoot-universal-links